# Found an algorithm that returns all nodes

Tags: algorithm, computer-science

in directed graph, each edge has a color C(e)ϵ{1,2,…k}
Found an algorithm that returns all nodes that are on circle traversal
Containing at least one edge of each color.

i think it related to SCC algorithm, but i didnt know how to start

any ideas that can help me?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Perform DFS to find cycles, and check each cycle found to see if it contains edges of all the colors.

Comment: you have any ideas if can i use the SCC alhorithm to answer that?
thanks.

Comment: SCC is based on DFS, so yeah, but I guess you still have to add custom code to the algorithm  (to check the cycles for example)

Comment: p.s. to check that a cycle has all the colors, you iterate the cycle and insert the color of each edge in the cycle into a set, and afterwards check if the size of the set is k.   btw, please vote for this answer if you find it useful